# How to check if SoundPool is ready to play without onLoadCompleteListener which was introduced in API 8?

Tags: android, soundpool

How did Android programs check if Sound was ready and played it in older versions of Android? Usually people tell to do Soundpool like this:

```
   soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.beep, 1);
```

But onLoadCompleteListener was introduced in API level 8 so it doesn't work. I can't get any sound playing from my program. What is the alternative way to check if sound is ready to be played? I just want to put some music on the background.

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious question-  why do you need to support older than version 8?  Less than .4% of all Android devices on the Play Store are version 8.  None of the versions lower than that are greater than .1%.  Most developers deploy for 10 (which has 7.8%) or even higher.  You're going to do a lot of work for very little gain aiming at devices before 8.

Comment: Unfortunately I happen to own one :/ and as a student I'm too poor to use 150€ for a new phone. I need to test it.

Comment: I would presume that `load()` is synchronous before API 8.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a moot point now, but before API 8 I would check to see if the sound was ready by attempting to play it at 0.0 volume and see if it returned a positive stream ID. If not I would sleep & loop in a "preparing" phase until it did play.

```
// Briefly play the stream at zero volume to get it decoded and prepped.
int stream = soundPool.play( soundPoolId, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f );
if (stream > 0)
{
  soundPool.stop(stream);
  isPrepared = true;
}
```